# Why aren't spaceships (usually) torn apart

Tags: thermodynamics, vacuum, rocket-science

This may have already be ask forgive me if it has but why aren't spaceships torn apart when in the vacuum of space? Is it just because they are strong enough not to be torn apart or because they are made in a certain shape?

Thanks for ur answers they are appreciated!

Comment: Hi and welcome! Can you explain why you think the would be torn apart? I'm not sure where your reasoning comes from

Comment: The gas bottles down the hall contain 1000's of psi - containing 1 atm (or a bit less) is pretty easy to do.

Comment: @JonCuster To be fair there is a (slight) difference between containing pressure, and withstanding external pressure.  Not a huge difference, but you may have to consider different things when making the vessels.

Comment: @JMac:  The gas bottles and the space ships are both containing internal pressure.

Comment: @James Derp, yeah.  I was thinking of vacuum vessels on earth.  Though you still do have some weird design considerations on the transitions between vacuum and atmosphere.

Comment: @JMac - as an interesting aside, the requirements of the ASME Pressure Vessel standard do not apply to situations with a pressure difference of 1 atm or less (per the scope of the standard itself). This is one reason no vacuum equipment is rated for a pressure different of greater than 1 atm.

Comment: @JonCuster To be fair, the ASME pressure code has a fairly high threshold until it falls into it's jurisdiction, from what I understand.  As far as I know, in Canada you don't need to really register your system or vessels until you get somewhere past ~2 atm gauge.  The thing is, that is applying to a system where you don't live inside the pressurized environment.  They only have to regulate relatively high pressure, because failure at those pressures can be lethal to people in the buildings.  When you live inside the pressure vessel, preventing failure is more critical.

Comment: @JMac - actually, for the US and ASME, the relevant number is a pressure difference of greater than 1 atm (and a diameter of more than 6", otherwise it is considered piping). Although then one has to distinguish between a pressure vessel and a boiler, but that is more for inspections and depends on the state law (again, US). But I think we've digressed well past the question!

Comment: "*Is it just because they are strong enough not to be torn apart or because they are made in a certain shape?*" These are overlapping. A fitting shape creates the strength. Direct material shear or bulk strength is rarely the weak part of an object, it is much more likely to be at a weak joint, pressure-concentrated corner, due to oscillation fatigue or the like.

Comment: Sentry I only believe they would be torn apart because of the stress put on them when initially taken off and for being in the vacuum of space for so long.

Answer (score 6):

By "torn apart" I assume you mean due to internal pressure, compared to the zero pressure of the vacuum.

Consider a propane tank, pressurized to ~100 PSI, compared to atmospheric pressure of ~14.7 PSI.  The tank does not explode, even though the pressure difference is ~ 85 PSI.  A spacecraft can easily be designed and made to be pressurized to 14.7 PSI and survive in a vacuum.

Comment: For the more SI-inclined: propane tank ~700 kPa, atmosphere ~100 kPa (kiloPascal = kiloNewton /square meter)